# How can I set a stack trace with Windbg?

Tags: windbg

I have Visual Studio 2010 Express and I have a program that doesn't work very well.
I would want to make a stack trace with Windbg,but I don't know the steps I have to do.
Thank you.
Regards,
Fran

Comment: Why don't you use the debugger in Visual Studio?

Comment: Because: When I debug the program(in Visual Studio) all works perfectly,but when I publish the program and I start the executable doesn't work(it says "Application1 has stopped working")

Comment: If you're going to use WinDbg, you need to tell us if this is a managed or native app.

Comment: What is the difference between managed and native app? Sorry,I'm a begginer in programming

Comment: It's a program(Windows form) made in Visual Studio 2010 Express. I think it's a .NET app.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a *native* stack trace in WinDbg you issue the `k` command.
To get a *managed* stack trace in WinDbg you issue the `!clrstack` command, but you first need to load up the correct managed runtime binaries and debugger extension, to do so, run this command as a shortcut: `!analyze –v` (See this [article](http://www.wintellect.com/blogs/jrobbins/automatically-load-the-right-sos-for-the-minidump) for details about what it is doing).

Also be aware that there are different versions of WinDbg for each processor architecture. If your compiled EXE is for x86, use the x86 version of WinDbg, and likewise for x64 builds.

References

- [Managed (SOS) debugging commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx)
- [WinDbg commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff539170.aspx)

Comment: Thank you,but...where I have to write the commands? What are the managed runtime binaries? Sorry,but I'm a begginer

Comment: @Frankcoding, at the bottom where there is a text box you can type in.  [Tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh406283.aspx)

Comment: @Frankcoding: Before there is a textbox to type commands, you need to attach to a process. Try [F6].